# jQuery event live click not functioning

Tags: jquery

I have a script which allows to display search results with the Bing API, example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHCT5/30/)

If you type something in, you will get two results. The var `WebOffset` allows to have results moving up in Total results. If the count for instance is 2 (as it is now) by setting `WebOffset=10` you will get two results after the first 10, so result 11 and 12. With this you can do a pagination like this:

```
$("li.pageli").live('click', function(){

WebOffset = "Web.Offset=" + $("a", this).html();

var v6 = $('#searchbox').val();
doSearch(v6); 

});
```

So based on the number of `li.pageli a` I can do a pagination. All was working well, then I noticed its not working in IE8.

So I was going to ask about this. However when I was setting up the example in JsFiddle I noticed it working there as well! Which is really strange because the exact same code is working for me on my desktop with Chrome/Firefox. So why is it not working in IE8 and JsFiddle?

Comment: did you try to clear the IE's cache?

Comment: @Bang Dao Yes, and I succeeded:)

Comment: I have experimented in the meanwhile and I believe the problem is in the way this is written: `WebOffset = "Web.Offset=" + $("a", this).html();` But I can't figure out how else to put or change this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem is...

Apparently 'href' should be written without spaces....So this is wrong:

```
<a href="#"> 20 </a>
```

And this is good:

```
<a href="#">20</a>
```

We all know that IE should be taken out in the woods and shot dead, but I find it strange that JsFiddle is also wired that way. Anyway case closed:)

Comment: If this answer your question than mark it as answered, so the question is closed